# How to use COUNT/COUNTIF to count cell value of a given range in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Sheet1 contains raw data: name (col-1), project (col-2), year.... etc (columns)
Sheet2 range (A1:A5) has the project name list

I need the count, in sheet2 (range B1:B5), of each project in the list from sheet1.

How can I use COUNTIF to do that?

Comment: Could you please show how the data looks? It is unclear from what you posted.

Comment: Taosique: please see the sheet posted by Paresh below.
Pnuts : i googled a lot for such codes. but failed to find/make one for my requirements.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following formula in *sheet2* to get the count of each projects listed in *sheet1*.

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!B:B,A2)
```

Lets take a look of how to implement the above formula.

Lets say you have following data in your *Sheet1*. Check the below image:

[image: Sheet1 Sample Data]

Now, lets take a look how to enter the formula to get the count in sheet2. Check the below image:

[image: Sheet2]

As you can use the formula enter in cell **B2** of *sheet2*. Using COUNTIF you can get the count of projects in *sheet1*

Comment: Paresh, 
Thanks for replay
I am able to use countif formula to do the job.
was looking for excel VBA code for the same.

Comment: If you got your solution you can upvote the answer and accept the answer by clicking check mark.